# ng-view not showing with resolve

Tags: angularjs, resolve

I am using resolve in this way (seems to be the standard way to do this way). But the view is not showing. Any ideas what I missed? Best Regards

```
angular.module('fifaApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/team/:code', {
      templateUrl: 'views/team_details.html',
      controller:'TeamDetailsCtrl as teamDetailsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        auth: function(UserService){
          return UserService.session();
        }
      }
    });
  });

  .factory('UserService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var service = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
      session: function() {
        var promise = $http.get('/api/session')
              promise.success(function(response) {
          service.isLoggedIn = true;
          return response;
        });
        return promise;
    };
    return service;
  };
  }]);

  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','auth',
    function($scope,auth) {
      $scope.auth = auth.response;
  }]);
```

And html:

```
<div class="team-details-container card">
  <div class="team-logo">
      <img title="Image Courtesy: Wikipedia"
           ng-src="{{teamDetailsCtrl.team.logoUrl}}">
  </div>
  <div class="name">
      <span ng-bind="teamDetailsCtrl.team.name"></span>
      (<span ng-bind="teamDetailsCtrl.team.fifaCode"></span>)
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <div class="label">
      <span>Nickname</span>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <span ng-bind="teamDetailsCtrl.team.nickname"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <div class="label">
      <span>FIFA Ranking</span>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <span ng-bind="teamDetailsCtrl.team.fifaRanking">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <div class="label">
      <span>Association</span>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <span ng-bind="teamDetailsCtrl.team.association"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <div class="label">
      <span>Head Coach</span>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <span ng-bind="teamDetailsCtrl.team.headCoach"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <div class="label">
      <span>Captain</span>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <span ng-bind="teamDetailsCtrl.team.captain"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is your real code then open console, there is an error.

Comment: I think you have to use `UserService.service.session()`

Comment: @FarzadYZ No that does not work either.

Comment: @user1665355 I think the problem is with your `.when()` declaration. You didn't include `$routeProvider` before `.when()`. E.g. `$routeProvider.when()`.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Sorry, a typo... Edited

Comment: @user1665355 Did you add `.otherwise()` in your routing code?

Comment: Yes Alberto, I just posted a part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$q` in service.

```
.factory('UserService', ['$http' , '$q', function($http, $q) {
    var service = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
      session: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = $http.get('/api/session')
        promise.success(function(response) {
            service.isLoggedIn = true;
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return service;
  };
 }]);
```

Comment: that is the original code, but I want to rewrite it like this guy does http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved/

Comment: Did u added ng-view in html ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93305/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-user1665355).